# Quicksort implementation bug

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort, array-algorithms

After a while, I was trying to implement quickSort on my own.
To me the implementation looks fine, but some test cases are apparently failing.

```
    class MyImplementation {
    public int[] sortArray(int[] nums) {
        quicksort(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
        return nums;
    }

    private void quicksort(int[] nums, int lo, int hi){
        if(lo < hi){
            int j = partition(nums, lo, hi);
            quicksort(nums, lo, j-1);
            quicksort(nums, j+1, hi);
        }
    }

    private int partition(int[] nums, int lo, int hi){
        int pivot = nums[lo];
        int head = lo + 1;
        int tail = hi;
        while(head < tail){
            while(head < hi && nums[head] < pivot) ++head;
            while(nums[tail] > pivot) --tail;
            if(head < tail){
                swap(nums, head, tail);
                ++head;
                --tail;
            }
        }
        if(nums[head] < pivot)
          swap(nums, lo, head);
        else
          swap(nums, lo, head - 1);  
        return head;
    } 

    private void swap(int[] nums, int i, int j){
        int temp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = temp;
    }
   }
```

It's passing in many cases, like these :-

```
   [5,2,3,1]
   [5,1,1,2,0,0]
   [7,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
```

but it's failing in the following test cases :-

```
[5,71,1,91,10,2,0,0,13,45,7]
```

the output I am getting is :-

```
[0,0,1,2,5,10,7,71,13,45,91]
```

instead of :-

```
[0,0,1,2,5,7,10,13,45,71,91]
```

I know, I can copy from somewhere to get the correctly working code, but can we figure out why this code is not working from an Algorithmic point of view!!
What is the logical flaw in this code?
How can we fix this with minimum changes and get a perfectly working code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite subtle. The bug is here:

```
private void quicksort(int[] nums, int lo, int hi){
    if(lo < hi){
        int j = partition(nums, lo, hi);
        quicksort(nums, lo, j-1);
        quicksort(nums, j+1, hi);
        //              ^^^  j+1 must be j
    }
}
```

The most subtle part is that it is not *in general* necessary to use `j` as the starting point of the "high" part to recurse on, but your partitioning algorithm requires it. So you will see various examples that recurse on different partitions, and they can be correct as well, in combination with whatever partitioning algorithm they use, but there is not much freedom to mix.

Your partitioning algorithm is based on Hoare's partitioning algorithm (see below), not Lomuto's algorithm. Lomuto's partitioning algorithm puts the pivot in its final position and returns its index, so that index can be skipped in the recursion. Hoare's partitioning algorithm, or your variant of it, does not quite do that. Eg in the case that the `else` branch at the end of your partitioning algorithm is taken, the pivot ends up at `head - 1`, while element at `head` has some arbitrary value not-less-than the pivot, all we know is that it belongs in the "high" partition but it has not been sorted yet and cannot be skipped.

In combination with Hoare's partitioning, it is common to see the recursion on [lo .. p] (where p is the index returned by the partitioning algorithm) and [p+1 .. hi], but that is not suitable in this case because your version of it returns `head` instead of `tail`, effectively making p one higher, so the partitions become [lo .. p-1] and [p .. hi].

---

As for this being similar to Hoare partitioning, consider that the important part of this partitioning algorithm looks like this:

```
    while(head < tail){
        while(head < hi && nums[head] < pivot) ++head;
        while(nums[tail] > pivot) --tail;
        if(head < tail){
            swap(nums, head, tail);
            ++head;
            --tail;
        }
    }
```

- Outer loop that iterates until the indexes "cross" (or meet)
- Two inner loops that iterate inwards, skipping elements that are already in the correct partition, to find two elements that are both in the wrong partition
- One swap to simultaneously put two elements into their respective partitions

And how does Hoare's partition algorithm work, well, the same way really (from wikipedia):

```
  loop forever 
    // Move the left index to the right at least once and while the element at
    // the left index is less than the pivot
    do i := i + 1 while A[i] < pivot
    
    // Move the right index to the left at least once and while the element at
    // the right index is greater than the pivot
    do j := j - 1 while A[j] > pivot

    // If the indices crossed, return
    if i >= j then return j
    
    // Swap the elements at the left and right indices
    swap A[i] with A[j]
```

This uses an early-exit instead of a while-loop as the outer loop, and therefore doesn't need an `if` around the swap, but apart from such minor details, it is the same thing.

If it is expressed this way, as opposed to how it is expressed in this question, it is less reasonable to modify it to always return the pivot index (expressed this way, it is also much less obvious what guarantee it actually makes on its return value). With the variant found in this question, that sort of naturally falls out as a possible modification, as seen in trincots answer.

By contrast, the important part of Lomuto's partitioning algorithm works like this (also from wikipedia)

```
  for j := lo to hi - 1 do 
    // If the current element is less than or equal to the pivot
    if A[j] <= pivot then 
      // Move the temporary pivot index forward
      i := i + 1
      // Swap the current element with the element at the temporary pivot index
      swap A[i] with A[j]
```

This is based on a totally different principle.

Comment: Worked and Accepted Sir. Thanks for the help, so very kind of you.
Where can I learn more about the partitioning algorithms by Hoare and Lomuto?
And quick sort in general.

Comment: The asker's algorithm is not Hoare's.

Comment: @trincot not exactly, but it follows the general structure (iterating from both sides until the indexes "cross") and has similar properties. It's further away from Lomuto's, the only thing it has in common with it is the swap in the end

Comment: That's not the only thing it has in common with Lomuto's. Also the exclusion of the chosen pivot index from the loop is typical for Lomuto's and not for Hoare's.

Comment: @trincot that proves that this partitioning algorithm isn't Lomuto's partitioning algorithm: it doesn't allow skipping the pivot index, and Lomuto's algorithm would have. The code in the `quicksort` function is written *as if* the partion algorithm was Lomuto's algorithm, but it isn't.

Comment: Well, you obviously look at it from a different angle. I see a clear *intention* to return the index of the pivot -- it just had an oversight.

Comment: I liked the detail with which Harold answered, yes I agree that it was an oversight and what was suggested by both of you, has worked and I am very very thankful to both of you for the illuminating answer. Many thanks and great regards.

Comment: @JohnDoe btw what I think is interesting here is that your partitioning algorithm plus trincots suggestion, essentially results in the good properties of Hoare's algorithm (using fewer swaps than Lomuto's) but without its quirk (ie conventionally not always returning the index of the pivot). I've not seen that combination before.

Answer (score 3):

The currently accepted answer fixes the issue, but actually, the Lomuto algorithm (which *is* the algorithm being implemented) should be able to use `j+1` as start for the second partition, since the pivot is expected to be at `j` and therefore doesn't need to be part of recursive sorts.

The real problem is that your `partition` method doesn't always return the index of the pivot:

```
        if(nums[head] < pivot)
          swap(nums, lo, head);
        else
          swap(nums, lo, head - 1);  
        return head;
```

In case of the `else`, the pivot is not swapped to index `head`, but to `head - 1`, and therefore the returned index should be `head - 1` in that case.

Here is a simple fix:

```
        if(nums[head] < pivot)
          swap(nums, lo, head);
        else
          swap(nums, lo, --head);  
        return head;
```

Comment: Yes, this makes sense, I should have returned (head - 1) in the else case, for sure, since that is the correct position, where the pivot should be going. I am really thankful to you for this.